# Selenium Chrome & Firefox WebDriver: Set HTTPS proxy in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, http-proxy, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've done plenty of searching however there is a lot of confusing snippets out there that are very similar.

I've attempted to use the `DesiredCapabilities`, `ChromeOptions`, `Options` and a series of arguments but nothing is working :( It fails to set a proxy.

For example (`ChromeOptions`)

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy=https://' + proxy_ip_and_port)
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-auth=' + proxy_user_and_pass)
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-type=https')

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
```

Another example (`Options`)

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--proxy=https://' + proxy_ip_and_port)
    options.add_argument('--proxy-auth=' + proxy_user_and_pass)
    options.add_argument('--proxy-type=https')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

I've also used `--proxy-server` instead of `--proxy-auth`, `--proxy-type`... etc even in the format of: `'--proxy-server=http://' + proxy_user_and_pass + '@' + proxy_ip_and_port`

Another example (`DesiredCapabilities`)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
                         'httpProxy': proxy_ip_and_port,
                         'ftpProxy': proxy_ip_and_port,
                         'sslProxy': proxy_ip_and_port,
                         'noProxy': '',
                         'class': "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
                         'autodetect': False}

capabilities['proxy']['socksUsername'] = proxy_user
capabilities['proxy']['socksPassword'] = proxy_pass

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe", desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

I've tried in Firefox too but the same issue happens, it uses the browser with my normal IP.

Comment: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg basically the same as I have posted, It doesn't work in the variation shown and the variation I tried, likewise a mix doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [latest documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/) (Jul 2020) you set the `DesiredCapabilities` for either `FIREFOX` or `CHROME`.

I've tested it for **Firefox**. You can check your browser's [connection settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox) afterwards to validate the proxy was set correctly.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST>:<PORT>"  # HOST can be IP or name
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,    # this is the https proxy
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    # Open URL
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

The proxy-dict itself is documented in the [Selenium wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#proxy-json-object). You'll see here that the attribute `sslProxy` sets the proxy for *https*.

I haven't tested it for **Chrome** though. If it shouldn't work, you may find clues  in Google's [ChromeDriver documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities). According to this you also need to instantiate the webdriver with the `desired_capabilites` parameter (which is then actually very similar to your example, so this is now more of a guess than a proven solution):

```
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['proxy'] = ... # like described above
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

Answer (score 0):

In module with Chrome driver:

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=<IP:port>')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,  service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

If you want use login and password you need to use seleniumwire.webdriver, not selenium.webdriver.
In terminal:

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

In module:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
proxy_options = {'proxy': {'http': f'http://{login}:{password}@<IP:port>','https': f'http://{login}:{password}@<IP:port>'}}   
driver=driver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=proxy_options,service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```