# Looking for this code in Firefox instead of Chrome (Selenium Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I have this code with Chrome, but I want the exact same code/function with Firefox. Any help is appreciated!

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format('server.address:8080'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405337/selenium-chrome-firefox-webdriver-set-https-proxy-in-python

Comment: Yes, I did. It does not work!

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
   
driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

You have to use  desiredCapability , the code is available in the selenium website itself.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/